# Set an attribute for an element

Tags: javascript, dom

I wrote a function for creating new elements. The code works correctly, but the function doesn't set that attribute for my element(my browser don't threw an error). I tried several methods but nothing worked.

```
function createElement(name, element, attribute, valueOfAttribute, text, indexOfChildNodes) {
    name = document.createElement(element.toLowerCase());
    var nodeText = document.createTextNode(text);
    name.appendChild(nodeText);
    var l = indexOfChildNodes;
    document.childNodes[l].appendChild(name);

    if(typeof attribute === 'array' && typeof valueOfAttribute === 'array'){
        for(var i = 0, len = attribute.length; i<len; i++){
            //name.setAttribute(attribute[i], valueOfAttribute[i]);
            var attr = document.createAttribute(attribute[i]);
            attr.value = valueOfAttribute[i];
            name.setAttributeNode(attr);
        }
    } else {
        return 'Check your "attribute" and "valueOfAttribute" arguments';
    }
}

createElement('next', 'button', ['id'], ['next'], 'Next', 1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because `typeof` for arrays will never return `"array"` in JavaScript.

You may either use modern [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) method instead or try old-school trick with prototype:

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(attribute) === '[object Array]') { ... }
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/QXrwZ/

Comment: yeah, typeof returns 'object' for an array, my bad. Array.isArray worked great!